# How to program the "mail package riddle"

Tags: algorithm, optimization

This riddle represents an encryption / key problem:

[image: Riddle]

The solution would be to send the package with a lock and the receiver sends the package back with a second lock. The original sender sends tha package again after removing his lock.

How would this be best accomplished for encryption use? (Note: this is not a homework or something similar, I was just wondering)

Comment: Try searching for Diffie Hellman key exchange protocol. The application is similar to the one in your riddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is somehow related to the [Diffie Hellman key exchange protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

each participant is choosing a single number to be his key, and sends the key encrypted to the other one.

The combination of both keys (which is the mutual key) is now easy to compute if you have one of the original keys, but if you don't, that's a hard problem to find out the mutual key (or any one of the private keys).